# About possible signatures of a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form.

Tags: abstract-algebra, bilinear-form

Say, I have a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on a vector space with Dim = $4$. Suppose I have a set of basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ and I know for any $i$, $<v_i,v_i>$ is positive. So what are the possible signatures?

I know $(4,0)$ is trivially a possible signature, just consider an Identity matrix.

However, about $(0,4)$, I do not know how to prove it is not possible. (I guess it is not)

So generally how to solve such kind of question, are there any useful tools?

Comment: collect your results in $G$, where $g_{i,,j} := \langle v_i, v_j\rangle$.  What can you tell about the signature/spectrum of $G$?  Not much except it has at least one positive eigenvalue (e.g. by checking the trace or using interlacing), and $\det\big(G\big)\neq 0$ since the form is non-degenerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be obvious $(0,4)$ isn't possible, since every vector has negative norm in that signature.

For the rest, it suffices to check $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ for every other possible signature $(p,q)$. (In theory, this might be useless idea if this is hard to do, but it turns out not to be hard to do.) Indeed, if you play around a bit you should be able to generalize to the following fact:

**Proposition**. A pseudo-Euclidean vector space admits a basis of vectors with positive quadratic form so long as it is not negative-definite signature.

*Proof*. Without loss of generality (by Sylvester's Theorem), we may as well consider $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ with $p>0$. If we pick any $v\in\mathbb{R}^p$ with $v\cdot v>1$ then there is such a basis

$$ \{e_1,\cdots,e_p,v+e_{p+1},\cdots,v+e_{p+q}\}. $$

Comment: Thx, but what is R^(p,q)?

Comment: It's standard notation for $\Bbb R^{p+q}$ with the standard nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form $$ x\cdot y=x_1y_1+\cdots+x_py_p-x_{p+1}y_{p+1}-\cdots-x_{p+q}y_{p+q}. $$ Sylvester's "Law of Inertia" says every nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form is equivalent to a standard one in some choice of coordinates.